# Cubic curve with a cuspidal singularity equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space

I want to show that an irreductible projective cubic $F$ with an cuspidal singularity $P$ is equivalent with the curve $G=Y^2Z-X^3$.
I know that exists an affine transformation that takes $P$ to $(0:0:1)$, the tangent line $T_pF$ to $Y$ and we'll have $F=aY^2Z − bX^3 − cX^2Y − dXY^2 − eY^3$.

Now I'm trying to construct affine transformations that leads to $a=b=1$ and $c=d=e=0$, but I'm having some troubles to find it. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is the points at infinity: your desired equation has an inflection point at infinity, while your current equation may not have this (at least if $bx^3+cx^2y+dxy^2+ey^3$ is not a cube). So you need to set things up so the portion of your curve at infinity is an inflection point.

In general, the way to start with this is to first find the inflection point via the Hessian: given an irreducible projective plane curve cut out by an equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ of degree $d$, if $d-1$ is coprime to the field characteristic, the common vanishing locus of $f$ and the [Hessian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $f$ contains all the inflection points on $V(f)$ (see Fulton's *Algebraic Curves* for full proof, for instance). It turns out that for an irreducible plane cubic over a field of characteristic not $2$, one will always get at least one nonsingular inflection point out of this, and one can then choose coordinates so that point is $[0:1:0]$.

From there, apply the techniques you've mentioned in the post: you'll find that when you substitute in $Z=0$, you must have your equation become $X^3$, so $c=d=e=0$. Now all you have to do is turn $aY^2Z-bX^3$ in to $Y^2Z-X^3$, which you can do via a clever linear scaling of $X$ and $Y$, which I give an explicit form of below in the spoiler.

> $X\mapsto abX$, $Y\mapsto ab^2Y$. This sends $aY^2Z-bX^3$ to $a^3b^4Y^2Z-a^3b^4X^3$, and then dividing by $a^3b^4$, one gets exactly $Y^2Z-X^3$.

---

For a proof of the theorem that there are exactly two singular projective plane cubics up to projective equivalence which works in all characteristics, one may prove that any  singular projective plane cubic is a projection of the twisted cubic in $\Bbb P^3$ from a point not on the curve. Projection from points on the tangent variety give cuspidal cubics, while projection from points on the the secant variety gives nodal cubics. I don't have a precise reference for this at present, but I think it should be in one of Harris' books. (One may also mess around with the pseudo-Hessian, a gadget designed to make the Hessian work a bit better in characteristic two, but this is a bit more obscure.)